# How to use Throttle/Debounce with Delegated event listeners? (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, event-handling, listener, throttling, debouncing

Trying to optimise the UX of some JS, including using Event Delegation and Throttling - but cannot seem to combine the approaches.
I'm looking for a way to listen for an event (scroll, mousemove etc.), identify the element, then call a relevant function (throttled).

I've tried various things, including trying to add a wrapper/intermediate function (handler) to pass multiple functions - but the end result is the same ... I end up with nothing back from the Throttle function.

The only thing I've managed to get to work is to produce a multi-throttle function, where I manually repeat the throttle functionality per function I wish to throttle.

```
function mythrottle() {
    var timer1, timer2;
    return function() {
        var now = Date.now();
        var last1 = timer1;
        var last2 = timer2;

        if(!last1) { timer1 = now;  callback1();  return; }
        if(!last2) { timer2 = now;  callback2();  return; }

        if(last1 + 500 > now) { return; }
        timer1 = now;  callback1();

        if(last2 + 1500 > now) { return; }
        timer2 = now;  callback2();
    }
}

function callback1(){
    console.log("callback 1 firing");
}

function callback2(){
    console.log("callback 2 firing");
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', mythrottle());
```

Ideally, I'd like;
1) a single eventlistener per event
2) the ability to filter/qualify the event (click on button or link or span etc.)
3) to then call the throttle function with a specific function (dependent on the filter/qualifier), passing the function and the delay
4) the throttle to handle the event with the delay (immediate fire, then wait)

That will avoid what I'm currently having to do, which is copy and ready several little chunks for each individual thing (and I'll have to wrap each with qualifiers/filters!).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing what you're trying to do. In any case, to make it work dynamically (adding/removing/configuring callbacks), you need a state. That's why I wrapped everything in a class.

Each callback will be tracked independently (to allow having different delays as per request). After instantiation, you can add more callbacks and/or events. Obviously, this example can be extended/improved, but I think is a good start and it should meet all your requirements.

If you have any question about the code below, please feel free to ask and I'll be glad to answer.

- NOTE: I've used modern syntax, but it can be easily rewritten to increase compatibility.

```
// -- THROTTLER --

class Throttler {

    constructor(args) {

        this.queue = [];
        this.throttle = typeof args.throttle === "number" ? args.throttle : 500; // GLOBAL THROTTLE
        this.threshold = typeof args.threshold === "number" ? args.threshold : 50; // GLOBAL THRESHOLD

        // BIND METHODS
        this.addCallback = this.addCallback.bind(this);
        this.addEvent = this.addEvent.bind(this);
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);

        if (Array.isArray(args.queue)) {
            // SETUP INITIAL CALLBACKS
            args.queue.forEach(this.addCallback);
        }

        if (Array.isArray(args.events)) {
            // SETUP INITIAL EVENTS
            args.events.forEach(this.addEvent);
        }

    }

    addCallback(cb) {
        if (typeof cb === "function") {
            this.queue.push({
                throttle: this.throttle,
                threshold: this.threshold,
                callback: cb,
                timer: null,
                ref: Date.now(),
                elapsed: 0
            });
        } else if (typeof cb === "object") {
            this.queue.push({
                throttle: cb.debounce ? undefined : this.throttle,
                threshold: this.threshold,
                ...cb,
                timer: null,
                ref: Date.now(),
                elapsed: 0
            });
        }
    }

    addEvent(eventName) {
        // ATTACH HANDLER
        window.addEventListener(eventName, this.handler);
    }

    handler(e) {

        this.queue.forEach((elem) => {

            const NOW = Date.now();

            if (typeof elem.throttle === "number") { // THROTTLE

                elem.elapsed += NOW - elem.ref;
                elem.ref = NOW;

                if (elem.elapsed >= elem.throttle) {

                    // EXECUTE CALLBACK
                    if (typeof elem.callback === "function") {
                        if (typeof elem.selector !== "string" || (typeof e.target.matches === "function" && e.target.matches(elem.selector))) {
                            if (typeof elem.eventName !== "string" || e.type === elem.eventName) {
                                elem.callback(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // RESET COUNTER
                    elem.elapsed = 0;

                }

                // KILL TIMER
                elem.timer && clearInterval(elem.timer);

                // RE-CREATE TIMER
                elem.timer = setTimeout(() => {

                    // RESET COUNTER
                    elem.elapsed = 0;

                    // RESET TIMER
                    elem.timer = null;

                }, elem.threshold);

            } else if (typeof elem.debounce === "number") { // DEBOUNCE

                // KILL TIMER
                elem.timer && clearInterval(elem.timer);

                // RE-CREATE TIMER
                elem.timer = setTimeout(() => {

                    // EXECUTE CALLBACK
                    if (typeof elem.callback === "function") {
                        if (typeof elem.selector !== "string" || (typeof e.target.matches === "function" && e.target.matches(elem.selector))) {
                            if (typeof elem.eventName !== "string" || e.type === elem.eventName) {
                                elem.callback(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // RESET TIMER
                    elem.timer = null;

                }, elem.debounce);

            }

        });

    }

}



// --- USAGE ---

// INSTANTIATE THROTTLER
const myThrottler = new Throttler({
    throttle: 1500,
    events: ['scroll', 'mousemove'],
    queue: [callback1, callback2]
});

// ADD ANOTHER EVENT
myThrottler.addEvent('resize');

// ADD CONDITIONAL CALLBACK
myThrottler.addCallback({
    callback: callback3,
    selector: '*',
    eventName: 'mousemove'
});

// ADD CUSTOM DELAY DEBOUNCED CALLBACK
myThrottler.addCallback({
    callback: callback4,
    debounce: 2000
});

// ADD CUSTOM DELAY THROTTLED CALLBACK
myThrottler.addCallback({
    callback: callback5,
    throttle: 3000
});



// --- CALLBACKS ---

function callback1() {
    console.log("CB 1");
}

function callback2() {
    console.log("CB 2");
}

function callback3() {
    console.log("CB 3");
}

function callback4() {
    console.log("CB 4");
}

function callback5() {
    console.log("CB 5");
}
```

Comment: Wow - no wonder I was struggling - that's complicated.  I'll have a play with it and see how long till I break it or get confused :D  Thank you!

Comment: Ok - had a quick play (couldn't resist) :D 
I instantiate a new throttler for each separate thing I want, correct?  (So I create a throttler for 'mousemove' and assign the callbacks I want, then create one for 'click' and the callbacks I want?).
And not sure if I broke something, but the default delay behaves more like a Debounce than a Throttle?

Comment: @ClearlyConfusedClyde I've just realised I'd only added debouncing. I've edited my answer to also support throttling (by default). You really only need one Throttler instance, then you can attach multiple events and callbacks to it. After that, set the rules using 'selector' and 'eventName' options.

Comment: @ClearlyConfusedClyde the 'selector' option accepts any CSS selector ('#myId', '.myClass', 'div > span', etc), and it will be tested against the event target element. By default, each callback will be fired for any target. The 'eventName' option allows you to fire the callback only for a specific event (EX: 'mousemove').

Comment: @ClearlyConfusedClyde I've edited the code one last time to allow throttling auto-reset when user interaction ends (threshold).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple `throttle` wrapper that can handle multiple callbacks and timers - however at the cost of:

- `window` namespace pollution (`window._throttleWait`)
- possible clash in callback throttling (throttling the exact same method twice will use the same thottle-wait timing)

But it's mighty small:

```js
function throttle(callback, limit = 150) {
    window._throttleWait = window._throttleWait ?? {}

    return function() {
      if (!window._throttleWait[callback]) {
        callback.call();
        window._throttleWait[callback] = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
          delete window._throttleWait[callback];
        }, limit);
      }
    }
  }
```